# java : Find a word in a string and replace it with a new word if its at a specific position

Tags: java, string

I have a sample string such as :

> " I Love cricket. I Love football. I Love tennis. I Love every game!!!
>   "

Now what I want to do is first time replace the the **I** (at position **1**) to "**We**". So it becomes

> " **We** Love cricket. I Love football. I Love tennis. I Love every
>   game!!! "

Again in the second run I want to replace **I** (at position **7**) to "**We**" .

> " I Love cricket. I Love football. **We** Love tennis. I Love every
>   game!!! "

So what I mean to say is replacing a word at a specific position with a new word. I tried following things so far:

1. `ReplaceAll` - worked for only when the words are uniques but fails in every other scenario.
2. `StringTokenizer` - used it go get an arraylist. replaced the word at the spcific position and then again appended all elements in the arraylist. Issue is the special characters are lost.

Please suggest a better way out of doing it.

EDIT: The delimeter can change and isn't specifically a " ".

Comment: Why is `I` in `I Love tennis` position 7?

Comment: Considering the words "I","Love" ,"Cricket" ,"I" ,"Love" ,"Football" now i want to change I (position 7) to we. Hope i am clear now.

Comment: So you mean to say 7th word. So position in your question are referring to words instead of chars.

Comment: @harry yes the position is in context to words.

Answer (score 1):

`yourString.split(" ")` gives an array of words. Assign new value to the specified index and then append the entries via space(" ") delimiter to produce new resulting string.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{
    String testString = " I Love cricket. I Love football. I Love tennis. I Love every game!!! ";
    String[] words = testString.split(" ");
    words[7] = "We";
    String newString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        newString += " " + words[i];

    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the delimeters between words can be anything varying from "space, ! .".

Comment: @Deva you should have already specified it in your question. am i wrong? if the delimiter is subject to change, using a regex might be useful as Dr. Dredel's answer suggests.

Comment: thanks for the above code snippet.and sorry for not being so clear. The delimeter is not specifically " " always, and could be something like a .,! .So the string could sometime be like "I Love Cricket.I Love FootBall.I Love Tennis.I Love every game!!!".

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead, use the `insert()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = 
    new StringBuilder(" I Love cricket. I Love football. I Love tennis. I Love every game!!! ")

sb.replace(1, 2, "We")
  .replace(35, 36, "We")

return sb.toString()
```

If you need to dynamically find positions of "I" and replace some of them with "We" then it's another story, but you get the idea.

replace(int start, int end, String str):
Replaces the characters in a substring of this sequence with characters in the specified String.
It returns this so you can chain several replace calls.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `replaceAll` use straight regex with [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). And just replace your first match rather than global. Or just use [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: first match? did you read the question carefully? he may want to replace 4th "I" match with "we", in that case this fails.

Comment: I don't believe this was how it was phrased before it was edited, but thanks for down voting. It's because of wonderfully diligent persons such as yourself that this site is as useful as it is.

Comment: I'm sorry for downvoting. thank you for your appreciations. modify your answer in a way that it shows how to replace nth regex match with a new string.